# Parachain doesn't produce blocks(collation wasn't advertised to any validator)

Tags: parachain, substrate-parachain-template, relay-chain, validator, parachain-collator

I'm currently engaged with the Polkadot relay chain version 1.1.0, and I've encountered an issue in the parachain where block production is not occurring. My configuration involves two validators in the relay chain and one collator in the parachain in the staging environment. Interestingly, when I switch the environment to local or change the chain type to local, the parachain begins producing blocks.